# I'm trying to render ONE component at a time to the DOM with an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been learning Reactjs for couple weeks now and I'm trying to build a game where a single object question is being rendered to the DOM however I'm unsure on how to do that? I've built a helper function to create all the components from that API response but of course it renders all my components and not just one. Is CSS involved to change the display or can it be done with some JS logic?

```
class Main extends Component{

    state = {
        quesArr: [],
        ansArr: []
    }



    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3500/questions')
            .then(quesArr => quesArr.json())
                .then(newQuesArr => {
                    this.setState({
                        quesArr: [...newQuesArr]
                    })
                })
                fetch('http://localhost:3500/answers')
                        .then(answerArr => answerArr.json())
                            .then(newAnsArr =>{
                                this.setState({
                                    ansArr: newAnsArr
                                })
                            })
                }



    render(){
       let questions = this.state.quesArr
       const renderQues = () => (
           questions.map((question, index) => <Question questionObj={question} key={index}/>)
       )


        return (
            <div>
                Questions go here:
                {renderQues()}
                Answers go here:



            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a map for that you just need to display the first question and then have a button to increase the active question index. (I added `//change` above the lines where I made changes)

```
class Main extends Component{

    state = {
        //change
        activeQ: 0,
        quesArr: [],
        ansArr: []
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3500/questions')
        .then(quesArr => quesArr.json())
        .then(newQuesArr => {
            this.setState({
                quesArr: [...newQuesArr]
            })
        })
    fetch('http://localhost:3500/answers')
        .then(answerArr => answerArr.json())
        .then(newAnsArr =>{
            this.setState({
                ansArr: newAnsArr
            })
        })
    }

    //change
    updateActiveQuestion = () => this.setState((prevState) => {activeQ: prevState.activeQ + 1})



    render(){
        let questions = this.state.quesArr
        const renderQues = () => (
        questions.map((question, index) => <Question questionObj={question} key= {index}/>)
    )


    return (
        <div>
            Questions go here:

            //change
            <Question questionObj={questions[this.state.activeQ]}/>
            <button onClick={() => this.updateActiveQuestion()}>Next Question</button>
            Answers go here:

        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is not a complete solution, it doesn't restrict the user from clicking next when there are no more questions.

Comment: This does give me more insight on to where to go from here on so thank you! But in order to access the array of objects which have the questions wouldn't I need to enumerate over it?

Comment: No, you can access the desired index of an array with this syntax array[index], which in my example I wrote `{questions[this.state.activeQ]`, so `this.state.activeQ`  is equal to the index of the question you want to show currently. Hope this makes sense.